# Mikrotik get запрос

Tags: html, get, mikrotik

Кто нибудь знает как на Mikrotik делать get запросы и возможно ли?

Comment: Eсть php библиотека для работы с  RouterOS API. https://wiki.mikrotik.com/wiki/API_PHP_class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Возможно, используя `/tool fetch`, например так:

```
/tool fetch url="http://some.domain/index.php" mode=http
```

[Документация по параметрам](https://wiki.mikrotik.com/wiki/Manual:Tools/Fetch).